# Как создать Picker по своему макету Android

Tags: java, android

[image: Дизайн нужного элемента]

Добрый вечер, в проекте нужно сделать Picker однако не обычный Число/Строка/Дата, а используя свой макет, пересмотрел множество библиотек однако у всех ты передаешь какой-то массив и все. Хотел найти что-то типо реализующее адаптер RecyclerView где можно использовать свой лаяут. Заранее спасибо всем, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Здравствуйте) Не понятно в чем вопрос, или сложность. Не можете найти как реализовать адаптер?

Comment: Добрый день, нет не могу найти как реализовать пиккер используя свой макет

Comment: Если вам нужно то, что на скриншоте, то вы можете взять любой пикер, который принимает строки и сформировать нужную строку из нескольких строк и/или чисел простой конкатенацией

Comment: @pavlofff А как я смогу узнать сколько отступов мне нужно чтобы цифры были по центру?